# What does 'vw' mean in this SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-view

What does vw mean in front of TournamentDetails?

```
SELECT * FROM vwTournamentDetails WHERE
    firstname='@firstName'
    AND lastname='@lastName' 
    AND --etc
```

Where is the table TournamentDetails coming from? We have no table named TournamentDetails.

Comment: I would also lookup using [Parameterized](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) SQL statements from C#. This example could suffer from SQL Injection.

Answer (score 20):

It's a [View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx), if you have a read of that link, Microsoft do a good job of explaining what a view is and why someone might use one.

"vw" is a common prefix for a View.

If you expand the "Views" section in SSMS you should see the View call `vwTournamentDetails`.

Here are the views from my AdventureWorks2012 Database:

[image: Adventure Works 2012 Views]

Comment: lol... it was a race to get the answer typed up faster...  +1 nice visual.  :)

Answer (score 2):

it's just a prefix, maybe a project name ...  `vwTournamentDetails` could even be `Stackoverflow`, it's just how someone named the table/view.

normally, we **database architects** tend to prefix the name with a **topic** or **area**, sometimes a **project**, a simple convention so we know things, when we thing that the same database could contain other tables not relative to what we are design them now... myself, I normally use the project short name, for example mv for the project `Mitivo`, or `tbl` for a Table `vw` for a `View`, it's how I have being writing tables for more than 20 years and that stick with us... old people... :)

bottom line, **it's just a name** :)

Answer (score 0):

It's just a prefix but it is a common prefix for views.

Answer (score 0):

The vw is likely a prefix for view. Look among tbe views, and you should find one named vwTournamentDetails.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an abbreviation for "view". So you don't have a table with this name but a view.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214068%28v=sql.80%29.aspx